# SQLite production deployment checklist for django and djangocms

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-cms, dev-to-production

I am going to deploy a djangocms website using sqlite db. 
My current db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 300,
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'NAME': 'project.db',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'PORT': '',
    'USER': ''
}}
```

I've run through django deployment checklist: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

...and reviewed notes related to sqlite:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#sqlite-notes

Looked through these docs as well:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES

I've found no specific security-related notes except for the general requirement to keep db password safe:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/#databases

I wasn't asked to provide db admin login and password during installation (djangocms installer didn't prompt for that).

Do I need to worry about this? Is it kept safe? Are there any other sqlite-specific points to the deployment checklist I need to worry about? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since SQLite is a serverless process called by django it doesn't expose any additional ports / connections. Most probably (prooflink needed) django uses the same superuser login and password for the base as that of the admin user. Therefore no additional steps / security measures are required.